# Ionic3 - Uncaught Error: Cannot find module '.'

Tags: ionic3

I´m knew in ionic and I have a very simple application that does not run anymore. I get following error in browser.
[image]

Comment: can you share the code of your app if its simple? normally such error means import path is invalid (no longer points to what you are importing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Vs Code added " /umd " to import statement like < `import { xxx } from "ionic-angular/umd";` >
just remove all " /umd " in your src folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vj8Yh.png)